# python script parsing multiple arguments

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have trouble passing parameters to my script.
Script launch command line : myscript.py -c Random
I'm using getopt in my code (given down there) but this code is not looping through the arguments because later on the program the tested_company varible is not defined, where did I go wrong?

```
tested_company=None
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hc:i", ['help', 'company', 'info']) #first argument ignored because zabbix giving it and being useless
except getopt.GetoptError as e:
    print (e)
    usage()
    sys.exit(3)
if not opts:
    #print ('No options supplied, only updating the database')
    print("3")
    sys.exit(3)
else:
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
            usage()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif opt in ('-c', '--company'):
            tested_company = arg
        elif opt == '-i':
            displayInfos=1
```

Comment: What do you expect `tested_company` to be? It's set to `None` on the very first line and then not reassigned at any point.

Comment: it is in the "elif opt in ('-c', '--company'):" part, when I'm specifying myscript.py -c XXXXXX , the tested_company should be XXXXXX but it's not

Comment: What is the actual error? Is it coming from this code or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing an equals sign after `company` in your getopt call. This code works for me:

```
import getopt
import sys

tested_company=None
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hc:i", ['help', 'company=', 'info']) #first argument ignored because zabbix giving it and being useless
    print(opts)
except getopt.GetoptError as e:
    print (e)
    usage()
    sys.exit(3)
if not opts:
    #print ('No options supplied, only updating the database')
    print("3")
    sys.exit(3)
else:
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
            usage()
            sys.exit(0)
        elif opt in ('-c', '--company'):
            tested_company = arg
        elif opt == '-i':
            displayInfos=1

print(tested_company)
```

Calling this with

```
> python .\script.py -c xxxx
```

gives

```
[('-c', 'xxxx')]
xxxx
```

Calling with

```
> python .\script.py --company xxxx
```

gives

```
[('--company', 'xxxx')]
xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

opts variable may not get initialised and is than called outside the try statement. Any particular reason why you can't do the following?

```
tested_company=None
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hc:i", ['help', 'company', 'info']) #first argument ignored because zabbix giving it and being useless
    if not opts:
        #print ('No options supplied, only updating the database')
        print("3")
        sys.exit(3)
    else:
        for opt, arg in opts:
            if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
                usage()
                sys.exit(0)
            elif opt in ('-c', '--company'):
                tested_company = arg
            elif opt == '-i':
                displayInfos=1
except getopt.GetoptError as e:
    print (e)
    usage()
    sys.exit(3)
```